# Download localfile through html

Tags: html

I have a problem: I want to download a file from my website using this link:

```
<a href="/path/to/file" download>Attachment</a>
```

But when i click this URL the link gets changed to:

```
localhost:9000/path/to/file
```

That means that my firefox does not find the file and cant download it, is there any fix for this?

Comment: Can you put the full URL in the href attribute?

Comment: The problem is I want to generate a downloadlink from a local file which gets uploaded by a user, that means there is no full path. I am using the full path to the file on the server atm

Answer (score 1):

use the full path in the href of a tag.

like this.

```
 <a href="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" download='download'>Click Here to download</a>
```

Comment: The problem is I want to generate a  downloadlink from a local file which gets uploaded by a user, that means there is no full path. I am using the full path to the file on the server atm

Answer (score 0):

hmm Have you tried forcing the download as such:

```
<a href="#" type="button" role="button" download="file.gif">Save GIF</a>
```

If this does not help, it most certantly means that your path is wrong. Are you forcing the real filesystem path?

```
echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: The problem is that the files attached to a message are not always the same type, that means I cant force them to a gif for example :/  The user is uploading the file to the server and I use the path where it's stored on the server